# Good Reasons for Not Disable the Windows SMB Service by Default?

Tags: windows, security, server-message-block, microsoft

Apart from File Sharing what are good reasons to not disable the Windows SMB service by default on a **corporate environment**?

This protocol seems to have a lot of security vulnerabilities and been using extensively for malicious lateral moves within the network.

Comment: What to jou mean with "SMB Service"? The (lanman)server or the SMB protocoll?

Comment: SMB1 should definitely be disabled. I would use the Windows Firewall for any other blocks instead of disabling the Server service entirely, because you may need to have exceptions and a way to manage them.

Answer (score 4):

When Windows servers are used in a a **corporate environment**, they mostly use an Active Directory infrastructure. At least there SMB (used by shares and share access by clients) is indispensable.

**Domain Controller**
In a Active Directory environment at least domain controllers definitely need administrative shares ...

> You may receive errors when you try to perform administrative tasks on a domain 
>   controller. For example, MMC snap-ins such as Active Directory Users and Computers 
>   or Active Directory Sites and Services may not start, and you may receive an error 
>   message that is similar to the following:

quote from: [Overview of problems that may occur when administrative shares are missing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/842715/overview-of-problems-that-may-occur-when-administrative-shares-are-mis)

... specially, for replication purposes, when jou have multiple domain controllers:

> Domain controllers without SYSVOL shared cannot replicate inbound because of
>   upstream (source) domain controllers being in an error state.

quote from: [DFS Replication: How to troubleshoot missing SYSVOL and Netlogon shares](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2958414/dfs-replication-how-to-troubleshoot-missing-sysvol-and-netlogon-shares)

To access an (administrative) share, SMB is needed.

**Domain Clients**
Workstations and domain member servers need the workstation service (also SMB) to access the domain controller to run logon scripts etc.

Answer (score 3):

The answer about SYSVOL is huge, so there's that. Also, a lot of workstation management/software deployment technologies depend on the target workstations having a c$ share for file distribution.

Comment: Not just file distribution, almost any sort of remote management depends on SMB, e.g., if you want to reboot a computer, see who is logged on, etc., etc.